# HDD write speed on gpt vs lvm, baremetal vs kvm

Tags: lvm, hard-disk, performance, kvm

I'm comparing write speed of HDD storage from two sources - baremetal, kvm and on two formats - gpt partition, lvm partition. Commands have been run thrice and I checked the average value. I used one seagate external HDD 1.5 TB connected to usb3 port for RPi 4B for testing this

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/darth_vader124/temp/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress`

baremetal-gpt ~ 45.8 MB/s

baremetal-lvm ~ 75.2 MB/s

why does lvm partition have a higher write speed? Is there some caching happening?

vm using file as disk (file stored on lvm partition in baremetal)

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/tdf/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress`

write speed - 65.3 MB/s

`dd if=/home/tdf/test.img of=/dev/null bs=8k count=10k iflag=nocache status=progress`

read speed - 249 MB/s

vm using whole lvm volume (lvm is on baremetal) as disk

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/tdv/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress`

write speed - 75.7 MB/s

`dd if=/home/tdv/test.img of=/dev/null bs=8k count=10k iflag=nocache status=progress`

read speed - 112 MB/s

both vms use lvm inside the disk (default option while installing ubuntu 20.04 server)

Are the above values expected? Specifically, why is there a difference in write speed in file vs volume disk. Read speed is considerably higher when using file disk. Is there some caching happening somewhere, despite using nocache in dd?

#### Edit-1:

I tried /dev/urandom instead of /dev/zero, by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935034/using-dev-urandom-for-dddisk-performance-test-is-a-good-idea-or-not).
I tried on lvm twice - first time, keeping the same configuration as before; second time, changing disk to gpt, and back to lvm again.

baremetal-lvm:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/run/user/1000/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress ; 
dd if=/run/user/1000/test.img of=/media/darth_vader124/temp/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress
```

write speed first - 66.6 MB/s ;
write speed second - 49.1 MB/s

```
dd if=/media/darth_vader124/temp/test.img of=/dev/null bs=8k count=10k iflag=nocache status=progress
```

read speed first - 131.33 MB/s ;
read speed second - 60.33 MB/s

baremetal-gpt:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/run/user/1000/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync status=progress ; 
dd if=/run/user/1000/test.img of=/media/darth_vader124/temp/test.img bs=8k count=10k conv=fdatasync
```

write speed - 55.4 MB/s

```
dd if=/media/darth_vader124/temp/test.img of=/dev/null bs=8k count=10k iflag=nocache status=progress
```

read speed - 93.7 MB/s

No other process is using the mount (found using iotop). I'm not really sure what is happening here. What could be other reasons for the disk performance to drop the second time in lvm?

#### Edit-2:

I turned off my system for a few hours and re-checked read and write bandwidth for baremetal-lvm again. The values are back to the ones observed during first run, ie

write speed ~ 73 MB/s, read speed ~ 119 MB/s

Do some variants of hard-disks lose read/write performance if they are run 24x7? Mine is a Seagate Expansion 1.5TB external drive. Or is there some other issue like hardware error?

Comment: Can you do a benchmark where you write literally anything but all zeros? The layers in your storage (the file system, LVM) might be correctly identifying these as all-zero storage and not be writing them to disk at all, but marking extents as sparse or similar. All-zero data is practically never a good benchmark! Plus, is `fdatasync` *really* what you want to benchmark? You're probably forcing your storage stack into transaction sizes that you'd normally not encounter.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on problem with fdatasync? My understanding is that it forces physical write before dd exits, which is what I want. I tried oflag=dsync - which to my understanding forces physical write of every block, before proceeding to next - and it gave speed of few hundred kB/s. I also tried oflag=direct, which was slower than non-direct, but I think this is never going to be used and there will always be some caching by kernel.

Comment: One possible reason for poor performance on the bare GPT partition is if the drive uses 4k sectors but the partition does not start on a 4k boundary.

Comment: The partition does start on a 4k boundary

Comment: Maybe your disk has a hardware error. You also have to test with much bigger test files. Your test files should be at least double the size of your RAM to ensure that you are not testing clever caching algorithms. LVM is probably caching everything. For a real test you need to use 2 identical disk drives. One drive formatted using LVM, the other GPT.

Comment: @paladin please look at Edit-2. Bigger files that are larger than RAM need to be stored somewhere, since generation from urandom ~ 26 MB/s. Bandwidth tests of HDD on such files will be affected by bandwidth of the other storage medium as well (I only have SD card on RPi, which is slower than the HDD). Please suggest some way to work around this.  I am testing both LVM and GPT using the same HDD, by reformatting appropriately.

Comment: Just use a harddisk which is faster in reading than your SD-card writes. Usually any modern harddisk is faster than an SD-card. Or use a better USB tumble drive, they should have also better read speeds than your SD-card writes.